# Read EXT4 GPT partition type SSD on windows

Tags: windows, gpt, ext4

I use [SharpExt4](https://github.com/nickdu088/SharpExt4) to read and copy data from an EXT4 SSD with an MBR partition type in Windows.

Now, I have a new card with a GPT partition type, as the new memory card is 4 terabytes and not able to use MBR anymore.

[SharpExt4](https://github.com/nickdu088/SharpExt4) does not support GPT, and I can't find any other library to use on Windows. Any suggestions?

I'm not looking for external tools such as [diskinternals](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/), etc., but I need to add this support to my own application.

Comment: Does the library need to be parsing partition tables at all? I believe Windows provides "raw" partition devices even if it doesn't understand the contents...

Comment: This might be better answered at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, and include in the ttile a search for a library and the *language*,  (presumably C#)